# Parse string with delimiter whitespace but having strings include whitespace as well?

Tags: c++, getline

I have a text file with state names and their respective abbreviations. It looks something like this:

```
Florida FL
Nevada      NV
New York     NY
```

So the number of whitespaces between state name and abbreviation differs. I want to extract the name and abbreviation and I thought about using getline with whitespace as a delimiter but I have problems with the whitespace in names like "New York". What function could I use instead?

Comment: what is wrong with `std::getline`? You have added such tag.

Comment: When I use getline(line, word, ' ') it views New York as two words. I want to put New York in 1 string.

Comment: why you use space argument? Don't you have each entry in separate line? Default value for third argument should just do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You know that the abbreviation is always two characters.

So you can [read the whole line](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), and split it at two characters from the end (probably using [`substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr)).

Then [trim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimming_(computer_programming)) the first string and you have two nice strings for the name and abbreviation.

Comment: Thanks that's helpful! What can I do if the abbreviations differ in length though?

Comment: @incnnu Do a reverse search for the "first" space in the string and split it there.

Comment: So I've tried splitting the line at three characters from the end (since each line ends with \n) in a while loop but of course that's not working for the last line in the file since there is no \n. Also I've tried using abbreviation = line.substr(line.find_last_of(' ')+1, 2); but it's not giving me the expected string. What's my mistake here?

Comment: @incnnu If you use `std::getline` to read into a `std::string` there won't be a newline at the end.

Comment: I do, but when I use while(getline(myIfStream, line) {cout << line;}; each line is printed in a new line in the console. Where is it getting this newline from?

Comment: @incnnu How do you open the file, as a binary or text file? This new problem seems like a good issue for a new question. But please then include a proper [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The systematic way is to analyze the all possible input data and then search for a pattern in the text. In your case, we analyze the problem and find out that

- at the end of the string we have some consecutive uppercase letters
- before that we have the state's name

So, if we search for the state abbreviation pattern and split that of, then the full name of the state will be available. But maybe with trailing and leading spaces. This we will remove and then the result is there.

For searching we will use a `std::regex`. The pattern is: 1 or more uppercase letters followed by 0 or more white spaces, followed by the end of the line. The regular expressions for that is: `"([A-Z]+)\\s*$"`

When this is available, the prefix of the result contains the full statename. We will remove leading and trailing spaces and that's it.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <regex>

std::istringstream textFile(R"(   Florida FL
  Nevada      NV
New York     NY)");

std::regex regexStateAbbreviation("([A-Z]+)\\s*$");

int main()
{
    // Split of some parts
    std::smatch stateAbbreviationMatch{};
    std::string line{};

    while (std::getline(textFile, line)) {
        if (std::regex_search(line, stateAbbreviationMatch, regexStateAbbreviation))
        {
            // Get the state
            std::string state(stateAbbreviationMatch.prefix());
            // Remove leading and trailing spaces
            state = std::regex_replace(state, std::regex("^ +| +$|( ) +"), "$1");

            // Get the state abbreviation
            std::string stateabbreviation(stateAbbreviationMatch[0]);

            // Print Result
            std::cout << stateabbreviation << ' ' << state << '\n';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```